# Left Alt key does not work properly on QWERTZ keyboard and iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, iterm

I am using the [QWERTZ keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) and I can't get the "@" (commercial at symbol) in iTerm2. As long as I'm using the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I'm only getting a question mark.

Using the same setup at my work keyboard works fine.

---

[image: QWERTZ Keyboard]

Comment: it is ok if you feel to downwote, but have the courage and leave a comment at least

Comment: I'm not going to vote either way, but isn't @ usually just shift/2 ?

Comment: not for me. its alt + L

Comment: Then you probably need to add your keyboard model & input language to your question. UK & US keyboards it's shift/2 Alt/L gives ¬